# How to create tabbed document environment using winforms?

Tags: winforms

How to create a tabbed document environment (like Visual Studio 2005/2008) using windows forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) allow you to create dockable window which can dock as tabs, tool windows etc just like in visual studio a Dockable MDI environment.

Comment: Thanks, i ve tried with DockPanel suite for my MDI application and it is really good and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

[TabControl](http://en.csharp-online.net/TabControl) is not enough?